# Laravel: Mass assignment insert new record or update exisiting

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, mass-assignment

I have a `User` model and a `UserInfo` model. they are a one to one relationship.

When a user signs up, he then goes ahead to fill a very large form with more info. That is contained in the `user_info` table, represented by `UserInfo` model.

I currently do this

```
$user->user_info()->create($request->all());
```

it works but if it is run the second time, it creates andother `UserInfo` record for the same user.

Is there a way i can do it so that if the UserInfo record already exists for this user, it only updtes the exisiting one

Is there a method like `updateOrCreate` that can work with Mass Assignment like this?

So that if the `UserInfo` record already exist on this `User`, it just updates with these new values

Comment: `$user->user_info()->updateOrCreate(['id'=>$user->id],$request->all());`

Comment: try the above query

Comment: @jaysingkar it didn't work. the error: `updateOrCreate() must be of the type array, integer given`

Comment: I have updated the query. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve updateOrCreate functionality by using `updateOrCreate()` method. 
**Usage:**

```
Model::updateOrCreate(
   ['primary_key' => 8],
   ['field' => 'value', 'another_field' => 'another value']
);
```

In your case, you can use fit in following way:

```
$user->user_info()->updateOrCreate(['id'=>$user->id],$request->all());
```

In place of id in `['id'=>$user->id]` use the name of your model's primary key.

Comment: In place of id in `['id'=>$user->id]` use the name of your model's primary key.

Comment: Thank you. It worked :). Edit your answer to include the comment you made, for other users